# Build runs but archive fails when referencing Firebase in multiple targets with CocoaPods

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

I want to use Firebase in a Siri Intent. I tried to run it and it works, but when I try to archive the app it fails to archive.

I use Xcode 11.2.1 on macOS Catalina 10.15.3 and CocoaPods 1.8.4.

The errors are:

- Multiple commands produce '/Users/matan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sendy-bqdzdmefsanhbvezkvawqizercwt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Sendy/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/GTMSessionFetcher.framework':
  1) Target 'GTMSessionFetcher-Core' has create directory command with output '/Users/matan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sendy-bqdzdmefsanhbvezkvawqizercwt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Sendy/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/GTMSessionFetcher.framework'
  2) Target 'GTMSessionFetcher.default-Core' has create directory command with output '/Users/matan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sendy-bqdzdmefsanhbvezkvawqizercwt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Sendy/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/GTMSessionFetcher.framework'
- Multiple commands produce '/Users/matan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sendy-bqdzdmefsanhbvezkvawqizercwt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Sendy/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/GoogleUtilities.framework':
  1) Target 'GoogleUtilities-00567490' has create directory command with output '/Users/matan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sendy-bqdzdmefsanhbvezkvawqizercwt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Sendy/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/GoogleUtilities.framework'
  2) Target 'GoogleUtilities-ac14cd06' has create directory command with output '/Users/matan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sendy-bqdzdmefsanhbvezkvawqizercwt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Sendy/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/GoogleUtilities.framework'

[image: archive errors]

Podfile:

```
project 'Sendy.xcodeproj'

# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '13.0'

abstract_target 'SendyPods' do

  use_frameworks!

  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
  pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift'

  target 'Sendy' do
    pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
    pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
    pod 'Firebase/Performance'
    pod 'FirebaseMessaging'
    pod 'GoogleSignIn'
  end

  target 'SendyIntents'

  target 'SendyIntentsUI'

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up changing the build system to the Legacy Build System that was used before Xcode 10.
You can switch to the Legacy Build System at File -> Workspace Settings -> Build System.

Comment: is there any downside to using the legacy build system?

Comment: @bze12 Build times are slower with the legacy build system

Comment: did you manage to update to the new build system?

Comment: @m1sh0 yes, but only after I switched to Carthage.